# TYPO3: How to get only parts of a record?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I want to built a content element with fields for text and images (I'm using the Mask extension for this) and use parts of the contents of it on further pages, for example as teasers.

Is it basically possible to put out only parts of a specific record, e.g. only the text and can an anybody give me a hint or an example how to?

Thank you for your help!
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are rendering is your selection. In mask you already use only a subselection of all available fields in a tt_content record. It s very complicated for an editor if you use fields in your rendering, that can't be edited.
Assume you have CE (content element) of type A with some fields which all are filled with data, then you change the type to B which has other fields. As you have not emptied the fields from type A you still can access them and render it in the frontend.

if you want to render teaser you use only those fields you think what gives you the teaser information.
In general records are handled complete.

you can define your own viewhelper which provide you with restricted data or you use typoscript where you do the rendering in typoscript and you have no access to individual fields.

e.g. you could use a `CONTENT` object, selecting data from CEs in another page:

```
temp.teaser = CONTENT
temp.teaser {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        // assuming context of a page, like in a menu
        pidInList.field = uid
        orderBy = sorting
        max = 1
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = header
        10.wrap = <div class="head">|</div>

        20 = TEXT
        20.field = bodytext
        20.wrap = <div class="content">|</div>
        20.crop = 100 | ... | 1

        wrap = <div class="teaser">|</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I first tried the solution with the two content elements which works fine! I have one question about the Typoscript way: If my full article is for example on page id 25 and I want to put the teaser for it on the root page (id 1), how I can achieve this? If I'm being correct, your script will put out the teaser on the same page, or am I wrong? (I have to say I'm not really an expert in typoscript...)

Comment: a typoscript `temp.`-object can not used anywhere while page generation as it is deleted before rendering starts. you need to copy it to something durable (`lib.`object, fluid-variable, menu, ...). anyway you need to modify or adapt the `select`: `pidInList` is responsible for the page where the content is gathered (you might use `pidInList = 25`, be aware of other parameters, I have no evaluation of `colPos` which might be necessary if multiple columns are available, I restricted it to only one CE, ...

Comment: Hi Bernd, After some trial and error I managed to rebuild your Typoscript code so that it works for my purposes - it now outputs all subpages as teasers on the parent page. Thanks again for your tip! But I still have a small problem: In the teaser I want to include a link to the page with the complete content. Unfortunately I don't get that: `typolink.parameter =  page:pid` only points to the parent page, not to the original one. Can you give me one more hint please?

Comment: first: `pid` = `Parent uID`, in TYPO3 that means the page where the record is stored. for pages this is the parent page. And still consider the context: `page:???` always accesses the record of the currently rendered page. if you are in a menu and want the uid of the currently processed page you need to access `data:uid` or simple the current field `uid`. `typolink.parameter.field = uid`